# Why my JS popup doesn't work on multiple element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm actually creating a forum from scratch. This script create a popup when we click on remove, i make 2 button remove but only one work.
Code:

Html Code ->

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styletest.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="#" id="remove_openpopup">remove</a>
    <a href="#" id="remove_openpopup">remove2</a>

    <div id="popup" class="popup">
      <div class="popup_content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <p>Are you sure you wan't delete this categorie ?</p>
        <button class="button_popup close_button">No</button>
        <button class="button_popup close_button" onclick='document.getElementById("remove").submit()'>Yes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var modal = document.getElementById("popup");

var btn = document.getElementById("remove_openpopup");

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
var span2 = document.getElementsByClassName("close_button")[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

span2.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

How can i make: when i click on remove it open my popup but remove2 open it too ?
Can you help me please ? :)

Comment: Sorry, what was the problem again? What is your expected result?

Comment: Due to your PHP `while` loop, you will end up creating multiple elements with the same ID "popup". This is invalid in HTML. It's also a fairly basic logical error...if they all have the same ID, how is the code supposed to know which one you are asking for when you run getElementById? Clearly there is no way to work that out. So it will always return the first one only. The others effectively do not exist as far as JavaScript is concerned. You need to use classes instead of IDs

Comment: P.s. You will have the same issue with your remove button and your form.

Comment: Ok I edit, tell me if you don't understand the problem @HastaTamang

Comment: How can i fix this @ADyson ?

Comment: What is the reason behind remove and remove2 with the same `id=remove_openpopup`?  use class instead as suggested above.

Comment: Seems like you have two elements which have  `id=remove_openpopup`. You cannot use multiple same id value in a page.

Comment: Ok i fix it:
<button onclick="test();">Test</button>
<button onclick="test();">Test2</button>

function test() {
 modal.style.display = "block";
}

Comment: And now how can i do for my close button ? (Yes and no)

Comment: I think the current code would work for close modal. I think you don't need to add close function on "Yes" since it seem to submit a form which would refresh the page.

Comment: @shinyatk yeah it work but, now, the form doesn't work. How can i make i think its cause of the `id`. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for a sample :)
In HTML, I changed `id="remove_openpopup"` to `class="remove_openpopup"`

```
<a href="#" class="remove_openpopup">remove</a>
<a href="#" class="remove_openpopup">remove2</a>
```

In `<script>`, I would do as below.

```
<script>
var modal = document.getElementById("popup");
var btns = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".remove_openpopup"));
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
var span2 = document.getElementsByClassName("close_button")[0];
btns.forEach(function(btn) {
  btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
  }
});
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
span2.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Ty, and how can i make my forms works for the 2 popup ? cause actually it doesn't work